# How to determine second order Markov chain by transition probability

Tags: markov-process

The following Eqation is for the first order, how can I write it for second order?
[image]

where |P is the transition probability.

Comment: Second order does not work with a matrix.

Comment: The easiest way to work with higher order Markov chains by still utilizing all the rules and equation of first order Markov chains is to use compound states. So e.g., if you have A - B - C - D and you want to study second order Markov chains you would build AB - BC - CD. You can work with Reset states to also model start and end states properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution of a second order Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ on some state space $S$ is characterized by:

- the initial distribution $\mu$ of $(X_0,X_1)$ on $S\times S$, such that, for every states $(x,y)$ in $S\times S$, one has $P(X_0=x,X_1=y)=\mu(x,y)$
- the transition matrix $Q$ indexed by $(S\times S)\times S$, such that, for every time $n\geqslant0$ and for every states $(x,y,z)$ in $S\times S\times S$, one has $P(X_{n+2}=z\mid X_{n+1}=y,X_n=x)=Q(x,y;z)$

Then, for every time $n\geqslant1$ and every sequence $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of states in $S$, one has$$P(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)=\mu(x_0,x_1)Q(x_0,x_1;x_2)Q(x_1,x_2;x_3)\cdots Q(x_{n-2},x_{n-1};x_n).$$